# Bath handles hanging and small chip in enamel

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

We let our house for 5 years to uncaring tenants. The bath (was new) now has the grip handles hanging off both sides and there is a small chip in the white enamel.

It was assumed the bath would need to be replaced but it is built in (with breeze block) and tiled all round, making it a big, expensive job!

I wonder if the handles might be removed? That would be OK by me. But how can the holes be filled? Are there stoppers I can buy? If so, where? I'm in the UK.

I know there are repair kits for the chip that I may be able to use.

We want to sell the house now and there are so many different jobs to do! Money has to be spent carefully.

Comment: A couple of close up pictures would help a lot here.